# How to compute the most optimal travel paths concurrently from mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to know what is the most optimal travel paths for each of some peoples at concurrently (let say for 4 hours). Those peoples start at the same time from City A (* see the table).

I have three mysql tables, as following:

**Tables**

```
people:
id    name
1     People A
2     People B
3     People C

city:
id    name
1     City A
2     City B
3     City C
...   ...
26    City Z

distance:
fromCity toCity distance (km) time (appox. travel in minutes)
1        2      5.0            30
1        3      3.0            25
1        4      6.0            42
...
2        3      4.0            27
2        4      7.0            53
2        5      6.0            50
...
```

**Result that I expected:**

```
People    Travel
Name      Route
========  ======
People A  City A -> City B -> City C -> City D
People B  City A -> City G -> City H -> City J -> City L
People C  City A -> City M -> City N -> City P
```

**Description:**
Every peoples start from City A, and each of those peoples have their own travel routes, and visited City only can referred to one people. Example:

```
Peope A has route:
City A -> City B -> City C -> City D.

=> Then City B, City C, and City D only visited by people A.

People B has route:
City A -> City G -> City H -> City J -> City L.

=> Then City G -> City H -> City J -> City L only visited by people B.
...
```

Right now, I only can query the city and the distance:

```
select
    distance.fromCity
    (select city.name from city where id = distance.fromCity) as fromCityName,
    distance.toCity,
    (select city.name from city where id = distance.toCity) as toCityName,
    distance,
    time
from distance
```

I don't know, how to compute the optimal paths for those peoples?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Yotam Omer <= I only can query the city and the distance. And I still don't know how to compute the optimal paths for those peoples.

Comment: This looks like a traveling salesperson problem. I'm not sure if MySQL is the right database for such problems since its a graph theory problem. Generally you would solve this kind of problem in its most naive way through brute force by trying all possible permutations and see what is the shortest. If you want something better than that you need to look into something like the A* algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a traveling salesperson problem. So what you need is an algorithm to find the shortest path.

An example of a stored procedure for Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm can be found here.

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=766&m=0

For a general understanding of the algorithm, you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: This is not an answer of the question.

Comment: If you expected a simple query then you will be disappointed I think. The linked stored procedure is in my belief the closest you will come to a ready-made solution. The problem is that you have relational data but your problem is a graph theory problem. If  you want to be able to write a simple query you might want to look into a graph database.

Comment: Should I have misunderstood the question please clarify what you mean and I can look into it again.

Comment: How if mySql has spatial data types? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-type-overview.html

Comment: What I see in your table 'distance' is that it is an adjacency list. It's basically the same as the table 'dijpaths' in the stored procedure. 

I don't see any geospatial data in your original question but I think it would not change my answer.

Comment: The dijpaths ouput is sorted, because the input is single person. Meanwhile what that I need is optimal for more multi persons, so the output is no sorted by ascending order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212125/discussion-between-jay-bee-and-jo0gbe4bstjb).